# Parallel NSight for Visual studio 2010 supports to debug on the server?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nsight

I have installed Parallel Nsight for Visual Studio 2010. Due to my research, it is not able to debugging on machines which dont have NVIDIA graphic card.

Therefore, I would like to debug it on the server (connecting to the server), would it be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can install Visual Studio and Parallel Nsight on your developer machine, and install Parallel Nsight on the remote machine with the GPU. Then you simply configure Parallel Nsight to execute on the remote machine.

Behind the scenes, when you "start CUDA debugging", Nsight will copy the executable (and any specified data files) to the remote machine and launch the task.

See the [Parallel Nsight](http://parallelnsight.nvidia.com/) website for more details and to check system requirements, as well as the documentation that is installed.

Comment: Another thing to make sure is that both your host and target machine reside on the same network and port 8000 isn't blocked.